# Histogram PDF Fitting - bin Variance Poisson or not

Tags: poisson-distribution, histogram, fitting

So my basic query is just because you've binned and counted the data into a histogram are the error bars on the bins necessarily the Poisson $\sqrt{N}$?

Longer explanation: I have an image of pixel values which represent brightness values. I am binning them into a histogram to get the PDF of the brightness distribution and then trying to fit a predicted model PDF to that. I'm fitting just using chi-square/least squares but if I use $\sqrt{N}$ as the error bars then there is basically never a "good" fit (reduced chi-squared of 3 or 4 for ~200 DOF) even for models we think should be good fits, the error bars seem too small.

We only have one set of real data so I tried using one model and generating a bunch (~30,000) of simulated images drawing the pixel values from the model and randomizing the positions and making histograms for each one. I then compute the mean of each bin from these simulations and the standard deviation. The standard deviations are definitely larger than $\sqrt{N}$. And now if I take the PDF from one of those and compare it the predicted model PDF it gives a good chi squared using the errors from the simulation but again still bad if I use Poisson variance.

But my advisor/boss doesn't agree/understand. He says we're just counting so there is no reason that the error bars should be larger. My idea is that they're larger/not Poisson because its not a totally random process. The number of pixels in a bin is dependent upon the underlying model and how well your particular realization/image samples that underlying distribution.

And we are not using the likelihood because its difficult to interpret for goodness of fit.

Comment: *If* the model is right and the observations are independent, it should be Poisson (In fact, if you condition on the total number of observations, you have a multinomial - which would be a bit smaller than the Poisson's $\sqrt N$). If you don't have independence or the model is wrong, it will be larger. Your simulation experiment would seem to eliminate the 'model is wrong' explanation in that case, so something you do is probably inducing dependence.